# What will be the value of this summation, given the recurrence relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,…,a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers which satisfies the relation $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a^2_n+1}$∀n∈N. Suppose that there exists a positive integer $n_0$ such that $a_{2{n_0}}=3a_{n_0}$. Then, find the value of $\lfloor \sum_{n=1}^{49} \sqrt{\frac{8}{8a^2_n +7}} \rfloor $ where the $\lfloor . \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer function.

**My attempt:**
For $n_0 =1$, we get the value of $a^2_1 = 1/8$.

Also using the relation, $a_n$ simplifies to $a^2_n = a^2_1 + n -1
=\frac {8n-7}{8}$.

Now substituting this value into the required sum, it reduces to $\lfloor \sum_{n=1}^{49} {\frac{1}{\sqrt n}} \rfloor $.
Using Python I have verified that this is 12, which is the correct answer, however the question requires to do it manually, and I am unable to do so.

Any hints on how to approach solving further, or any other methods of going about the problem are appreciated.

Comment: A rather unusual form of exercise...

Comment: Do you begin your sequence at index 1 (it looks so) or index 0 ?

Comment: @JeanMarie as per the question, I started at index 1 as it is defined for all natural numbers

Comment: The problem with notation $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is that it begins with $n=0$...

Comment: @JeanMarie I do not think there is a value of $a_0$ which works on the $a_{2{n_0}}=3a_{n_0}$ condition

Comment: @JeanMarie: there is no clear consensus as to whether $\mathbb{N}$ contains $0$. I myself prefer $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$, but it is good when it is stated what the assumption is.

Comment: It is an extension of a problem of the 2013 Saudi Arabia Mathematical Competition where the value of $a_{46}$ is asked. Ask Google with these keywords "SAMC 2013 - Art of Problem Solving"

Comment: @JeanMarie correct, however it is more so the sum part that I'm having problems with rather than the series. I have figured out $a_n =\sqrt (a_1 + n - 1)$ and that $a_1 = 1/\sqrt 8$ so I can solve that, but am not sure how to go about with the summation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- Consider $b_n=a_n^2$ and rewrite the question in terms of $b_n$
- You need to find which values of $n_0$ work and give a credible value of $a_1$.  It look to me as if $n_0=1$ does.

Added:

- You have since found $a_n=\frac{n}{8}-\frac{7}{8}$.  This makes
  $\lfloor \sum_{n=1}^{49} \sqrt{\frac{8}{8a^2_n +7}} \rfloor = \sqrt{1}+\sqrt{\frac12}+\sqrt{\frac13}+ \cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{48}}$ rounded down  which is not easy by hand, but  $\int\limits_{1}^{49} \frac 1 {\sqrt{x}}\,dx = 12$ and $\int\limits_{0.25}^{49} \frac 1 {\sqrt{x}}\,dx = 13$ so the answer is going to be $12$ when rounded down, using $\int\limits_{n}^{n+1} \frac 1 {\sqrt{x}}\,dx < \frac1{\sqrt{n}} < \int\limits_{n-0.75}^{n+0.25} \frac 1 {\sqrt{x}}\,dx$

Comment: Thanks. Using these I've reduced the sum, I'm new to stack exchange, so should I edit my question to show the progress or include it in a comment?

Comment: @HridaiKhurana Editing your question for progress would be good - if you had a full answer, you could answer your own question

Comment: I've made the edit, hope its clear

Comment: @HridaiKhurana I have suggested a way of finding the the answer is between $12$ and $13$ so $12$ when rounded down

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted the answer. However, is there a reason to why you took the limit to be -0.75 of the lower bound, or is it a theorem I am unaware of?

Comment: @HridaiKhurana $\pm\frac12$ also works with any decreasing function and might be used in general, but ${\frac14}$ has a nice square root in this particular case

Comment: got it, thanks so much